# Cocos2d-x 2.2.6 iPhone 5s resolution rate error?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am using cocos2d-x 2.2.6 and I find something interesting. iPhone 5s 's resolution rate is `640x1136`. But I got `640*960` from the function `pEGLView->getFrameSize()`

AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()

```
CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

CCSize screenSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
CCLog("screen size: %f %f",screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

How can I get exactly the right resolution rate of iPhone 5s or other device? I have tested the `Director->getWinSize()` function, I got `0*0`.

Comment: did you try `pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);` and then getting `getWinSize()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, just add a `Default-568h@2x.png` picture to the project directory. According to this post 
[iPhone 5 letterboxing / screen resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398819/iphone-5-letterboxing-screen-resize) .